# dynamic select box duplicating results

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to build mutiple select boxes that dymaically populate then next select box based on the option selected.

it seems to be working but the 3rd select box has duplicate results and i can't see why

here is the JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.selectchange').one('change', function() {

    var x = $(this).children(":selected").attr("value");
    console.log(x)

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "id=" + x,
        url: "../complaints/index.php/complaint/get_complaint_sub_types",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {

            var x = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");

            $.each(data, function(id, value) {

                var opt = $('<option />');
                opt.val(value.id);
                opt.text(value.name);
                $('.selectchange1').append(opt);


                $('.selectchange2').one('click', function(event) {

                    var y = $(this).children(":selected").attr("value");


                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        data: "id=" + y,
                        url: "../complaints/index.php/complaint/get_complaint_description",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(data1) {

                            if (data1 != " ") {
                                var z = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
                                console.log(z);
                                $.each(data1, function(id, value) {

                                    var opt = $('<option />');
                                    opt.val(value.id);
                                    opt.text(value.name);
                                    $('.selectchange2').append(opt);

                                })
                            };

                        }
                    })
                });

            });
        }

    });

});

})
```

here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7mg3ume5/2/

Comment: JSfiddle enhance the possibility to get an answer faster.

Comment: Jsfiddle is incomplete .Pls Check!

Comment: the data is stored in mysql db so i can't provide any more info. its only the 3rd select box which is duplicating results from the ajax call

Comment: We can't correctly answer your question because you didn't provide enough data. I guess you should empty `$('.selectchange2').html('')` before append it

Comment: updated the fiddle to show what happens in the 3rd select box